# What is the recommended schema for paginated GraphQL results

Tags: graphql

Let's say I have `users` list to be returned. What would be best schema strategy among following.

1. Users returned contains only the data of user as follows, separate query is used for pagination details. In this query the downside is we need to pass same filters to both `users` and `usersCount` query.

```
query {
   users(skip: 0, limit: 100, filters: someFilter) {
     name
   },
   usersCount(filters: someFilters)
}
```

Which return following

```
{
  results: {
    users: [
      { name: "Foo" },
      { name: "Bar" },
    ],
    usersCount: 1000,
  }
}
```

2. In this strategy we make pagination details as part of users query, we don't need to pass `filters` twice. I feel this query is not nice to read.

```
query {
  users(skip: 0, limit: 100, filters: someFilter) {
    items: { 
      name 
    },
    count
  }
}
```

Which returns the following result

```
{
  results: {
    users: {
      items: [
        { name: "Foo" },
        { name: "Bar" },
      ],
      count: 1000,
    }
  }
}
```

I am curious to know which strategy is the recommended way while designing paginated results?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow the official recommendation on [graphql](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#end-of-list-counts-and-connections) spec,
You need to switch to cursor based pagination.

This type of pagination uses a record or a pointer to a record in the dataset to paginate results. The cursor will refer to a record in the database.

You can follow the example in the link.

Answer (score 0):

[GraphQL Cursor Connections Specification](https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm)

Also checkout how GitHub does it here: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/interfaces#node